# OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor Showing while trying to export csv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, export-to-csv, file-descriptor, file-writing

I want to save or export a csv file in python with some data. But it's every time showing this error, even the code has no error I think.

Please help me out from this problem.

```
import csv

myFile = open('products.csv', 'a')
with myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerow(['France', 'Paris'])

OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_first_webscrap.py", line 32, in <module>
    writer.writerow(['France', 'Paris'])
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Is it possible that something else is closing the myFile file descriptor? I think we need to see a bit more of your code to know why you're getting the `"Bad file descriptor"` error

Comment: Change to `with open('products.csv', 'a') as myFile:`

Comment: I've tried with that way...but it's not working